# WWNs,WWPNs and Fibre Channel addresses

Tags: fibre-channel

Lots of contradictory on these subjects and I don't know why.

My first question is about the 64 bit WWN. One reference claims the terms WWN and WWPN are synonymous. An online source seems to refute this. They say:

> A WWPN (world wide port name) is the unique identifier for a fibre
>   channel port where  a WWN (world wide name) the unique identifier for
>   the node itself. A good example is a  dual port HBA. There will be two
>   WWPN's (one for each port) and only a single WWN  for the card itself.

**Question #1:** Which is correct? I’m almost positive I read that every “Port” has a WWN.

My next question is about the 24 bit FC address that is dynamically allocated to a port when it is introduced to the switch. The Domain ID field is defined as: "a unique number provided to each switch in the fabric."

**Question #2:** Do Domain IDs only apply to switch ports? For example what would the Domain ID be for a HBA? None? The same as the switch port it is connected to?

**Question #3:** My last question is about the Name Server of a switch. A book example shows the routing of a message through the switch. It uses the WWNs of the source and destination ports to route the message. I am assuming that the Name Server must associate the WWN and the FC address in some way in order to route the message, correct?

Comment: For WWNN/WWPN: It depends on the hardware and the adapter.  Some implementations the WWN, WWPN, WWNN are the same across all ports, sometimes not.  As an example, we have a dual-port HBA in an AIX system and "fcstat" pulls up different WWPN (what the fiber switch looks for) and WWNN for each port.